# Multiple clients web application design

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, mongodb, database-design

I've to design a web application to support multiple clients.
I'm thinking to have a MongoDB with the username or email of each user and the name of the connection string of each user.
And with the connection string get the SQL database of the client.

But I'm not sure if this is the best approach.

Do you have any other suggestion?

Answer (score 0):

Had situation close to you.
We used 1 common db(parent), where stored connections per clients and simple iterface to control child database's(they are separated, you can create manualy or automaticly as many db's per client, as you want or as many clients.

Based in what way you want to find clients. Our system used client per url/ Every client had own url and own db. So in code, we check url, then get from main db connection string and init context with specified connection.

You need provide more details, to get more info. Based on your goal, solution can be different.

Answer (score 0):

I saw some projects with URL based approach... However, if you want your application more dynamic like let say migrating from server side to client side application and you don't want your URL change... I would say, your "user based" approach is more ideal in my opinion. Good luck.

Answer (score -1):

If you have many clients with their databases then you must made different web application, even if they are copy/paste the one to the other

If you have many clients under the same url, under the same web application, then you can have one database and there you separate them, inside the database.

**The web.config is not offering for frequent change the connection - you setup this ones to work and you forget it.**

Every time you change the web.config you create a serial of events, and restart the application, recompile it if find some reason... etc